# LevelHelper add Complex Object(Body, Sprite, Joint) single object

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, box2d-iphone, levelhelper

I am new to LevelHelper.

I have created a Car+2 wheels using Wheel Joint(The same as the one in Wheel Joint of LevelHelper youtube tutorial).

My question is how can I programmatically add multiple Car with all the wheel and physics???

Should I add separate Sprite and Add my joints and then bind them???

Help is much appreciated

Regards;

Answer (score 0):

I Was in the same sittuation as you are now. I have created track and my bike object in separate level and created separate levelhelperloader object for track and bike and add it to the b2world.

This is worked for me. I hope it will work for you also.

Comment: for me, i used Cocos2d-x rather than Cocos2d. Levelhelper has less support code for Cocos2d-x than Cocos2d. And the support is slow. I am considering TexturePacker and Phsysics Editor.